# Passing PHP variable to javascript function with quotes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I need to pass these values to a javascript function in the head. The problem is when pulling from the DB some are more than one word, and using a href it cuts it off at a space when passing using javascript:function(vars), and I can't get onclick to work at all. I've tried all sorts of combinations of quotes and brackets around the variables ("",'',/", and {) as well as putting quotes around the ones I know will have more than one word before passing (see below). Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
    require('config/dbconfig.php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
        /* execute statement */
        $stmt->execute();

        /* bind result variables */
        $stmt->bind_result($idn, $titlen, $categoryn, $descn, $postdaten, $authorn);

        /* fetch values */
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            //echo 'id: '. $id .' title: '. $title;
            echo "<table border='0'>";
            $shortDescLengthn = strlen($descn);
            if ($shortDescLengthn > 106) {
                $sDCutn = 106 - $shortDescLengthn;
                $shortDescn = substr($descn, 0, $sDCutn);
            } else {
                $shortDescn = $descn;
            }
                        $titlenQuote = "'". $titlen ."'";
                        $descnQuote = "'". $descn ."'";
                        $authornQuote = "'". $authorn ."'";
            echo "
                <h1>". $titlen ."</h1>
                <tr><td>". $shortDescn ."...</td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick='readMore(". $idn .",". $titlenQuote .",". $categoryn .",
                            ". $descnQuote .",". $postdaten .",". $authornQuote .")'>Read More</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Written by: " . $authorn . "</td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src='images/hardcore-games-newsbar-border.png' width='470px' /></td></tr>
            ";
        }
        echo "</table><br />";

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();
    }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

And the function it's going to in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readMore(id,title,cat,desc,post,auth) {
        alert(id +","+ title +","+ cat +","+ desc +","+ post +","+ auth);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html('This dialog will show every time!').dialog({autoOpen: false,title: 'Basic Dialog'});
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        $dialog.title = title;
        $dialog.html(desc);
    }
</script>
```

This is a page using load() in the main index page. I've had issues with dialog too, but it's not even hitting that point yet so thats the next step. In case need to know, all jquery includes are on the main index page. The load() is going into a div on the index page, and this works fine so far.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that already. Like my OP says, it's not necessarily the actual passing of it as it is passing the entire string of the variable. It cuts off. Should I refer a link to the top of this page for you to re-read it?

Comment: It's nice seeing someone *finally* using `MySQLi` instead of `mysql`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same type of quote for both the attribute value delimiter and the JavaScript string delimiter; don't do that. Also, `json_encode` the values instead of just wrapping them in quotes, like so:

```
echo "
    <h1>". $titlen ."</h1>
    <tr><td>". $shortDescn ."...</td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick='readMore(". $idn .",". json_encode($titlen) .",". json_encode($categoryn) .",
    ". json_encode($descn) .",". json_encode($postdaten) .",". json_encode($authorn) .")'>Read More</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Written by: " . $authorn . "</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src='images/hardcore-games-newsbar-border.png' width='470px' /></td></tr>
";
```

… and you'll also want to HTML-encode them.

```
echo "<h1>$titlen</h1>";
echo "<tr><td>$shortDescn...</td></tr>";
echo '<tr><td><a href="javascript:return false;" onclick="'
    . 'readMore(' . $idn . ',' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($titlen)) . ','
    . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($categoryn)) . ','
    . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($descn)) . ',' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($postdaten)) . ','
    . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($authorn)) . ')">Read More</a></td></tr>';
echo "<tr><td>Written by: $authorn</td></tr>";
echo '<tr><td><img src="images/hardcore-games-newsbar-border.png" width="470px" /></td></tr>';
```

ProTip™: `<tr>` can't be directly after `<h1>`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was hoping there was something to add quotes, just couldn't find it for whatever reason. Worked like a charm.

Comment: What if the title is, say, "It's raining"?

Comment: Or, more maliciously, `' onmouseover='alert(document.cookie)' nothing='`?

Comment: One of my test titles is "Promise Last Test" and it works just fine using the above. I won't be having any special characters in there most likely.

Comment: @icktoofay - Or using `console.log` instead of `alert` so that it is not obvious.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff: That's just an example... showing the user his/her own cookie is not exactly what I'd call dangerous :)

Comment: @minitech - I know that. :-) If someone did get access to the database and edited something, they could, with lots of scripting, make any other client's browser use a contact form etc. for spam, and then it would be hard to trace.

Answer (score 3):

You're currently doing something like this:

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='doSomething('" . $someData . "');'>...";
```

As you noted, this will not work because the quotes conflict. There's a quick way to fix this, but I think it would be better if you changed it a little bit more.

First, start by putting your data in attributes:

```
echo "<a ... data-title=\"" . htmlspecialchars($title) . "\" ...>...";
```

Note how I am escaping the `title` before I put it in there. You can add more attributes like that, but you should make them all start with `data-`.

Next, apply a `class` to it. For example, `read-more`.

```
echo "<a ... class=\"read-more\" data-title=\"" . htmlspecialchars($title) . "\" ...>...";
```

Now you can bind event listeners to it. Say all of the items were contained in a `div` with an `id` of `items`. You could then do this in the JavaScript:

```
$("#items").on("click", ".read-more", function(e) {
    var me = $(this);
    var title = me.attr('data-title');
    alert("The title is:\n" + title);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You could then extend that to pop up a dialog or whatever you wanted it to do.

---

## Why this way and not the 'easy' way?

This way is a start to separating the content, presentation, and behavior, which is generally considered a good thing. Before, you had `table`s for layout and presentation mixed with the content mixed with inline JavaScript for behavior; a big soup of stuff.

Separating this all out aids maintainability and can often bring better load times if the common things are put into separate files and cached by the browser. If it's all a big soup, the browser can't cache the pieces separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
function login(t) {
alert(t);
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
print "<input type='button' name='button' value='button' onClick=login('$id')>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```